# Ubuntu 12.04: wireless mouse, cursor goes crazy, blinkering/slow and impossible to do anything

Tags: wireless, mouse

So i have this problem. When i put wired mouse, no problem. When i put the wireless mouse connection, then the mouse cursor goes crazy, blinkering, and moving slow and its impossible to do anything with the mouse, keyboard works but that isnt wireless anyway.

The wireless mouse isnt new though, it was released in 2002 according to wikipedia. But it worked fine with Windows still. Maybe its a mouse software issue?

Mouse specs:
Logitech MX700
M-RY81

Batteries are not the issue, recharged with separate charger, work well in a flashlight

Restart doesnt change the issue, still blinkering and moving by itself and impossible to do anything because of that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the computer is concerned this is a wired mouse. The charging cradle is also the wireless base-station, which then emulates a usb mouse to the computer. I would suspect a fault with the mouse of base-station charging cradle.